# Spring data rest query pagable and sortable

Tags: spring-data, spring-data-rest

how can I solve the following problem. At the moment I implement an query, which search in db for string in rows. It works great, I can pageing the result in frontend but I can't sort. If I call the following url and add the sort params as url parameter It no sort my result.
How I can solve the problem

web/api/orders/search/findSearch?page=0&sort=number,asc&searchText=hello&size=25

```
@Query("SELECT o FROM Order o where"+
        "(lower(o.number) like('%' || lower(:searchText) || '%') " +
        "or lower(o.name)  like('%' || lower(:searchText) || '%') ) " +
        "or lower(o.created)  like('%' || lower(:searchText) || '%') " +)
Page<Order> findSearch(@Param("searchText") String searchText,  Pageable pageable);
```

Comment: That should actually work as you expected. Any chance you provide a tiny sample project that shows this failing and create a ticket in our [JIRA](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAREST)?

Comment: I try it, but now I get an exception if I add an query. Here is my repo https://github.com/aBuder/springDataRestSample

Comment: I solved the problem. I had an bracket to much.  the query should now look like this.

@Query("SELECT o FROM Order o where"+
        "(lower(o.number) like('%' || lower(:searchText) || '%') " +
        "or lower(o.name)  like('%' || lower(:searchText) || '%') " +
        "or lower(o.created)  like('%' || lower(:searchText) || '%') " +)